# useState in next.js when navigating using Link (next/link)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a next.js page to display a post, like a blog, and I use Link to move from a post to another. To show the proper post I use another component, something like this (note that I cut a lot of code for semplicity)

```
const Index: NextPage<PageProps> = (props) => {
    const router = useRouter();
    let post = props.post;

        return (
            <>
                <Post post={post}/>
                <Link href={`/post/${encodeURIComponent(props.next.id)}`} passHref={true}>
                    <a>next post</a>
                </Link>
                <Link href={`/post/${encodeURIComponent(props.previous.id)}`} passHref={true}>
                    <a>previous post</a>
                </Link>
                
            </>
        );
};

export default Index;

export const getServerSideProps = async (context) => {
    const session = await getSession(context);
    const pid = context.params.pid;
    let postManager = new PostManager();
    let post = await postManager.getPost(pid);
    let siblings = null;
    if (post) {
        siblings = await postManager.getSiblings(post);
    }

    return {
        props: {
            post: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(post)),
            next: (siblings && siblings.next) ? JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(siblings.next)) : null,
            previous: (siblings && siblings.previous) ? JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(siblings.previous)) : null,
            session: session,
        }
    };
};
```

what it is strange is that in the Post component seems like useState is not executed after the first time I load the page:

```
const Post = props => {

    const [title, setTitle] = useState(props.post.title);

    console.log(props.post.title);
    console.log(title);
```

here when I load the page "directly" the two values are the same (which is fine). Then when I click on Link (in the page component), the second console.log is showing the value from the content I loaded directly.

This doesn't happen if I take off Link and I leave `<a>`, but of course using Link is faster so I'd prefer to use it.

How can I "force" useState to set the correct value every time props has changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are staying on the same page with shallow routing the component is not freshly re-rendered but the props are updated. This is intended react/next behaviour.

Add to your Post component the following:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setTitle(props.post.title);
  }, [props]);
```

This will update the state when the props are updated.
Let me know if you have any questions.